# Router or Switch can defend against ARP spoofing attack?

Tags: network, attacks, attack-prevention, router

I'm learning about ARP spoofing attacks. Can a router or switch defend against ARP attacks?

Comment: Yes it can. There are many answers to this on the Internet. Have you looked at those?

Comment: @EmileCormier not helpful in the comment thread to a question. Please raise this sort of thing in our Meta. Also note that I did not *answer* with "just google it" but asked if research had been done.

Answer (score 1):

Many modern routers implement arp-spoofing protection as an inbuilt feature.

As Sunny points out, old-school switches ran on Layer 2, and typically didn't analyse Layer 3 (Network Layer) whereas routers do. That said, more modern switches may incorporate functionality that you would expect in a router, and even up to Layer 7 handling QoS and Deep Packet Inspection.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a switch is not intelligent enough to prevent arp poisoning. However if the traffic between two host reach the router then it can prevent arp poisoning.
See this http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst6500/ios/12-2SX/configuration/guide/book/dynarp.html